# How to make a startup disk/dvd from iso

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to install Windows Server 2008 in a lab environment. I have downloaded the .iso of the install image and burned it to a DVD. However, the DVD with the .iso file burned on it is not bootable. What do I need to do? I'm doing this from a Vista client.

Answer (score 4):

You don't burn the .iso file to the DVD. An .iso file is a container, you need to burn the *contents* of the .iso to a DVD. Windows 7 has this capability built in. If you're on Vista, you should use PowerISO, Nero, Roxio, ImgBurn, etc etc etc. There's probably going to be an option for "Burn an image to a disk" or "Burn an iso"